# How can I retrieve currently logged in user's name?

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I have a jax-ws/metro 2.2 web service with username authentification running on glassfish 3.1.2.
How can I get the name of acutally logged in users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the name the user logged in with via `WebServiceContext`'s `getUserPrincipal().getName()`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310165/calling-getuserprincipal-in-a-web-service-returns-anonymous) for potential gotchas.

As for obtaining the names of any other user logged in, you'll have to work something out yourself in your web-apps with some common store (application level? db?) - that would be a violation of security policy that Java EE's not going to support out of box.