# Secure Webservice Client on Glassfish

Tags: web-services, security, glassfish, client

I have an secure external webservice at URL https://my-webservice-path?wsdl, and i want to connect to use this. This is a 2-way ssl.
I create a webservice client in following:

1. Create an java application Application1
2. at Project window, click Application1 icon -> new -> Web service client
3. paste my URL at WSDL URL, client type is JAX-WS, package: com.mypackage
4. finish

But an error appears: Error: An I/O error occured. Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

And i can not create Web Service References. I use Glassfish 3.0.1 server.

I tried to replace the alias s1as in keystore.jks and cacerts.jks of the Glassfish by my keypair and certificate, but it still fails.

I also tried to use wsimport parsing wsdl file but fail:(

I posted this question in Oracle Forum at http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2214292&tstart=0 but get no answer.
i've tried to solve this for 2 days :(

What can i do now to solve this problem?
Plz help me, thank you!

Comment: hi, i used wireshark to check and see that. when i used browser to invoke this service, the client sent client's certificates to server. everything was ok. But when i used java code, no certificates was sent to server. And the handshake failed.

hope this information help!

Answer (score 0):

please check out the answer from Catchwa in [Mutual-authentication with web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240931/mutual-authentication-with-web-services). The steps to implement a glassfish based mutual authentication are described in detail.

Comment: hi all. I solved the problem. It was a bug of Netbeans 6.9. If you use Netbeans 7.0, it is ok. Hope this help