# Mutual auth with Java (client cert PFX file) and no access to environment

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service, mutual-authentication

I have a Java Spring Boot web application deployed on an Azure App Service (not embedded Tomcat, but using App Service Tomcat PaaS). This application needs to make a call to a REST API, that is secured by mandating mutual authentication, i.e. with a client certificate.

I have the PFX file, and I don't have access to the environment to add the certificate to the keystore, truststore, etc.

Is there any way to call the REST API in Java, with just the client certificate, which possibly is part of the web application resources ?

Comment: What exception (full stack trace) are you getting when you try the API call, can you update your question with it?

Comment: @JGlass  I'm not getting any exception, I have to achieve mutual authentication  when I make a REST API call from server to client. On client side I have enabled clientCertEnabled flag by following steps given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth). I need some help on how to send the certificate from spring boot application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: based this SO article got things working and also explains some things [mutual authentication with web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240931/mutual-authentication-with-web-services) - but - it looks like you will need access to the azure servers keystore.  Hope the article helps!  If it does and you get it working, you might answer your own question here to build up your reputation!